# How to make reusable containers with different features in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hello I am using container to make an AppBar have a colored gradient the code is

```
Container appBarGradient(){
  return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              end: Alignment.topRight,
              colors: <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.white, Colors.blue])));
}
```

I am also building a bottom AppBar and would like to keep the gradient a consistent color, thus I am reusing appBarGradient. But I would like to add a child to appBarGradient and I noticed that it has a .child method but I don't know how to use it.

```
BottomAppBar mainBottomBar(){
  return BottomAppBar(
    child: appBarGradient().child

  );
}
```

What are these methods for? Can I use them to build ontop of preexisting widgets? I don't know what this is even called so it's very hard for me to search in the documentation for what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can make a `Gradient` widget like this:

```
class Gradient extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  
  Gradient({this.child, Key key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              end: Alignment.topRight,
              colors: <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.white, Colors.blue])),
      child: child);
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like any other widget, like so: `Gradient(child: Text("I'm an example"))`

Answer (score 0):

Different gradient color can be used like this for different scrren.
Your can assign color to different screen where you want

```
class Gradient extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  List<Color> color =[];

  Gradient({this.child, Key key,this.color}) : super(key: key,);

  @override
  _GradientState createState() => _GradientState();
}

class _GradientState extends State<Gradient> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 100,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                colors: widget.color
            )
        ),
        child: widget.child);
  }
}
```